# Angular: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ___ of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm getting these errors even though the values renders in the browser. I'm not sure how to fix this.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined

**Component.ts:**

```
teams: Team[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.getTeams();
}

constructor(private m: DataManagerService, private router: Router) { 
}

getTeams(): void {
  this.m.getTeams().subscribe(teams => this.teams = teams);
}

select(em: Team){
  this.router.navigate(['/teamView',em._id]);
}
```

**Component.html:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Team name</th>
      <th>Name of Team Leader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor='let team of teams' (click)="select(team)">
      <td>{{team.TeamName}}</td>
      <td>{{team.TeamLead.FirstName}} {{team.TeamLead.LastName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
</div>
```

**Team.ts:**

```
export class Team {
    _id: string;
    TeamName: string;
    TeamLead: Employee;
    Projects:{};
    Employees: {};
}
```

**Object:**

> https://lit-coast-73093.herokuapp.com/teams

**DataManagerService.ts**

```
teams: Team[];
projects: Project[];
employees: Employee[];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
}

getTeams(): Observable<Team[]> {
    return this.http.get<Team[]>(`${this.url}/teams`)
  }

getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(`${this.url}/projects`)
}

getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.url}/employees`)
}
```

Comment: .length was just getting the size of the object. It works if I remove  <td>{{team.TeamLead.FirstName}} {{team.TeamLead.LastName}}</td>

Comment: @John C : can you edit and add the code for ``select(team)`` to your question ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI select(team) is in component.ts

Comment: What is the content of ``Project`` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr *ngIf='teams.length > 0' *ngFor='let team of teams' (click)="select(team)">
  <td>{{team?.TeamName}}</td>
  <td>{{team?.TeamLead?.FirstName}} {{team?.TeamLead?.LastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Possibilities :
a) Teams object hasn't been populated yet. Hence there is nothing to iterate over
b) Your API response doesn't have all the expected properties.

Adding checks like I suggested above should fix your problem. LMK if I can explain further.

Comment: Actually I think you should change the `*ngIf` here to: `*ngIf='teams != null && teams.length > 0'` otherwise if `getTeams()` returns null, this will error with `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: This doesn't even compile. `Error: Template parse errors: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *`

Answer (score 3):

Because `teams` is probably not yet available,

you can try this way:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Team name</th>
      <th>Name of Team Leader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor='let team of teams' (click)="select(team)">
      <td>{{team.TeamName}}</td>
      <td>{{team.TeamLead?.FirstName}} {{team.TeamLead?.LastName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tutorial-2yzwuu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You don't need the ? after team, as team will never be null. If it were null, the `*ngFor` would never be entered.